# How I can CMD to read multiple IP's from a text file and print the result in one file?

Tags: cmd, ip, ping

How I can CMD to read multiple IP's from text file and print the result in one file?

Such as this command
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO ping -n 1 10.22.29.%i | FIND /i "Reply">>c:\ipaddressesServer1.txt

the result will be

Reply from 10.22.29.1: Destination host unreachable.

Reply from 110.22.29.2: Destination host unreachable.

Reply from 10.22.29.3: Destination host unreachable.

Reply from 10.22.29.4: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Reply from 10.22.29.5: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=128

the only that I need how to read multiple IP's from a text file rather to read a range of IP's.

Comment: Type `for /?` to see how.

Comment: Yes, but how it could be read from input file?

Answer (score 1):

Here, try that command:

```
for /f %a in (input.txt) do (ping -n 1 %a | FIND /i "Reply">>ipaddressesServer1.txt)
```

This will loop through each line of the file input.txt and read IPs from the file in this format:

```
10.22.29.1
10.22.29.2
10.22.29.3
10.22.29.4
```

Comment: this is can be on CMD or batch?

Comment: Simply use a .bat or .cmd file.

Comment: Thanks a lots :)

I just add the path and remove one % and it's working


for /f %a in (C:\\devices.txt) do (ping -n 1 %a | FIND /i "Reply">>c:\TestAgin.txt)

Comment: I thought you are using a batch script file. Of course only use one % when running commands inside the Command Prompt. I'll correct my answer. If that was helpful, i would be glad if you check this answer as helpful.

Comment: Oh Okay, Yesterday I wasn't able to vote up because my reputation didn't fill the requirement of voting. I had another question and i will be glad if you helping me now how I can find more than string and print it out because now I getting replay and to find more that but I couldn't such as find "Request"

Comment: Do you still need help? I do not understand what you mean.